# is there any tools which give the list of function usage/call/ details in an project(bulk code)

Tags: c++, linux

Thanks in advance
C++: LINUX machine
Please May i know ,is there any tools which give the list of function usage/call/ details in an project(bulk code).

EX: int fun(int var){return var;}

some where in the code the function is called like this : 
fun(10);
fun(21);

Answer (score 0):

[cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) does exactly what you want. Run it in your project like this:

```
cscope -R
```

Then in the curses interface, type in the function name to search for. It will show a list of matching calls and the arguments passed in.
You can jump to each one pressing the letter in the menu.

Finally, press Ctrl+d to exit the program.